# How to add timestamp over an capture image?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a camera app. In which I need to capture an image and just after that before saving I need to add some text over the captured image. Is it possible to edit the captured image at a run time in android please suggest me?

[demo output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZvv.jpg)

activity_camera.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Open Camera"
    />
```

CameraActivity.java

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Camera camera;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        Button btnCamera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Camera Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Test.jpg");
                Uri iImageOutputUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                AppPermission appPermission = new AppPermission(CameraActivity.this);
                if (!appPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
                appPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Camera Text 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Process result for camera activity.
        // If camera take picture success.
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            Toast.makeText(this, currentDateandTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show time stamp on the clicked image, you can follow these steps:

1. After image clicked so it in the image view.
2. Upon that image view there is already been a textview set textview with time stamp and take the screenshot programatically of relative layout which contains both image view and textview.

If you need help anywhere, just let me know.